# Trying to reference a dll that has reference to the NLog.dll getting exception

Tags: c#, dll

So I have a dll that I am getting from my colleague who worked on that project. He is using NLog.dll but he said he didn't get it from NuGet. When I reference his dll in my project it gives the following issue. Please help.

[image: Compatability issues between dlls]

Comment: The error message says that this dll has a dependency to NLog with an assembly version of `3.0.0.0`. Often (but not always!) the assembly version corresponds with the file version and/or the version number of the published software / library package. Thus, try using NLog **3.0** (you should be able to get it through Nuget) and see whether it resolves your problem.

Comment: Thanks I will try it